# C# bitwise negation ! check equivalent

Tags: c#

Given the following C++ Code:

```
void Check(DWORD64 ptr)
{
    if ( ! (ptr & 0x8000000000000000) )
        return;
}
```

In C# this results in the following Error:

> CS0023    Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'ulong'

How do I bitwise check the ptr parameter in C#?

Comparing to not 0?

```
void Check(ulong ptr)
{
    if ((ptr & 0x8000000000000000) != 0)
        return;
}
```

or checking for 0?

```
void Check(ulong ptr)
{
    if ((ptr & 0x8000000000000000) == 0)
    return;
}
```

Googleing for this questions leads to all sorts of answers on different bitwise operations but I couldn't find an answer for this specific negation with exclemation mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When operator `!` "logical not" is applied to a numeric value in C or C++, it produces a result as follows:

- `1` if its operand is zero
- `0` otherwise

C's conditional statement `if` interprets `0` as "false" and any non-zero value, including `1`, as "true". Therefore, your second option is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The second one.  C++ would treat any nonzero value as true, so the ! check on an integer was effectively equivalent to !(value != 0) or (value==0)